# real-time plotting to a TK window using python3

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, real-time

I am trying to plot in real-time to a tkinter window in python3.

I am attempting to wrap my window in a class.

my code shows the graph, but data is not being plotted.  Here is the code:

```py
#! /usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import tkinter
import time
import numpy as np

matplotlib.use("TkAgg")

class Window(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.master.grid()
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.t, self.y = [], []
        self.init_window()
        self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animate, interval=1000)

    def init_window(self):
        # set window title
        self.master.title("PlotSomething")
        # run show_graph
        self.show_graph()

    def animate(self):
        self.t.append(time.time())
        self.y.append(np.random.random())
        self.ax.clear()
        self.ax.plot(self.t,self.y)

    def show_graph(self):
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, self.master)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1, column=1)
        canvas.draw()

    def client_exit(self):
        sys.exit()

def main(args):
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    app = Window(root)
    root.mainloop()
    return 0

if __name__=="__main__":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

Please let me know what the issue is.

Bonus if you can help me get the real-time plot stuff into a separate class that I can call with my tkinter window.

I obviously need some learning on how to create and call classes using tkinter.

As always thank you for your support!

Comment: One thing to know about class instances is that they are garbage collected if not stored in a variable.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I edited my code to add `self.ani = anim...`  does this address your comment?  That however did not solve the animation issue.

Comment: Oh, you create the animation before the figure has a canvas to live in. However the timer for the animation is a tk object, so it needs a tk canvas to exist.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest  I think I understand the issue, how do I go about solving it?

Comment: Create the animation after the canvas.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank you for your help, I changed the order in my `__init__` function.  This did not solve my problem.  I am sorry but I am not understanding the hickup

Comment: It definitely solves the problem of the animation not being started. Maybe you now get a different problem; but I don't know what that is. Please clarify.

Comment: Try changing `def animate(self)` to `def animate(self, *args)`.

Comment: @acw1668 this was the solution.  program now works.  Thanks to you both.